# Access exported file in consumer Conan recipe

Tags: python, conan

I have a Conan recipe that packages executable and exports python file, e.g.:

```
class MyPackageConan(ConanFile):
    name = "my_package"
    version = "1.0.0"
    exports: "script.py"
    
    def package(self):
        if self.settings.os == "Windows"
            self.copy("*", dst="bin", src="bin/Windows")
        # if Linux, etc.
```

What is the easiest way to access functions from exported python script in another recipe that requires this package?

```
class MySecondPackageConan(ConanFile):
    requires = "my_package/1.0.0"

    def build(self):
        # import foo() from script.py
```

---

Seems to works nicely for this case:

```
class MyPackageConan(ConanFile):
    name = "my_package"
    version = "1.0.0"
    settings = "os", "arch"      # I omitted it for simplicity in previous example

    def package(self):
        self.copy("script.py")
        if self.settings.os == "Windows":
            self.copy("*.exe", dst="bin", src="Windows")
        # elif Linux, Macos, ...
    
    def package_info(self):
        self.env_info.PYTHONPATH.append(self.package_folder)
```

Comment: According to this post: https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/7283#issuecomment-651808730 it seems that I should rather copy `script.py` to package rather than to export folder (next to conanfile.py). Then I access it with self.deps_cpp_info["my_package"].bin_paths

Answer (score 0):

> I have a Conan recipe that packages executable and exports python file, e.g.:

When you mention *executable*, do you mean .exe? If yes, there is a good [guide](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/devtools/create_installer_packages.html) in Conan docs how to do it. You have to declare `os` and `arch` if you are packaging binaries.

> What is the easiest way to access functions from exported python script in another recipe that requires this package?

It's explained to in Conan [docs](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/extending/python_requires.html#introduction), but all methods are in same recipe. Your case requires a little change, let's take a look in an example:

```py
# foo.py
def foobar():
    print("FOOBAR!")
```

```py
# foo_req.py
from conans import ConanFile
import sys

class FooConan(ConanFile):
    exports = "foo.py"

    def package_info(self):
        sys.path.insert(0, self.recipe_folder)

from foo import *
```

```py
# conanfile.py
from conans import ConanFile

class Pkg(ConanFile):
    python_requires = "foo_req/0.1@user/testing"

    def build(self):
        self.python_requires["foo_req"].module.foobar()
```

Now let's build all this:

```
conan create foo_req.py foo_req/0.1@user/testing
conan create conanfile.py foo/0.1@user/testing
```

Here, the file `foo.py` is what we want to import, but first we need to export it to conan recipe folder. Is it really required? No, but once exported we have it cached.
We also manipulate pythonpath to use recipe folder, so we can import foo module later.
Once imported, it will be part of Conan python require modules.

Comment: The point is that I want executables (.exe files) and python script to be part of my conan recipe and hence I can't use `python_requires` as such recipe should not package anything, but use `export` only.

Comment: Why don't split them in separate packages? You still can add executable package as requirement for that package with python_requires